# Azure data flow cross join

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, dataflow, paas

I have one requirement that I need to achieve with Azure data flow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkOmY.png)

As you can see in output that we can easily using cross and split function in sql query but same thing how can I achieve using data flow.

Comment: I'm afraid Data Flow can not achieve that.  You'd better tell us what you have tried and get.

Comment: Hello Leon the above requirement I need to achieve using data flow, left hand side is my table & right hand side is my output I need to store in blob storage.

Comment: Since you can using the cross ans splint function in SQL query to get the result you want, you could also run the query in the Source dataset.

Comment: Did you want to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in ADF Data Flows.

[image]

1. From your flat file source, add a derived column
2. Create a new column called "countries".We'll take your multi-valued column and spit it into that array using this expression: split(country,',')
3. Use Flatten to denormalize into the output you asked for
4. Flatten: Set unroll to countries (I called it myarray in the screenshot) and take out the original comma-delimited field from your field mappings.

[image]